# number of index data each row in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want to create and show number sort ascending data in datatables like in this picture
[index number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSxGI.png)

and I don't have sorted data number in database and my json data 
this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataya').DataTable({
             lengthChange: false,
             ajax: {
                     url: "http://localhost/jdih_webservice/api/xxxx",
                     dataSrc: ""
             },
             columns: [
                     { data: "id_dokumen"},
                     { data: "judul"},
                     { data: "subjek"}
             ],
             select: true
        });
    $('#search').click(function(){
      var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
      var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
                var myTable = $('#dataya').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
                    "bDestroy": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "data": [],
            "columns": [{
                "title": "ID",
                "data": "id_dokumen"
            }, {
                "title": "Judul",
                "data": "judul"
            }, {
                "title": "Subjek",
                "data": "subjek"
            }],
                    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
        });

      if(start_date != '' && end_date !='')
      {
        var startDate = new Date(start_date);
                    var tglmulai = startDate.getFullYear();
        var endDate = new Date(end_date);
                    var tglselesai = endDate.getFullYear();
        let url = 'http://localhost/jdih_webservice/api/xxxx';
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((out) => {
            var resultProductData = out.filter(function(a) {
            var createdAt = new Date(a.tgltetap);
                            var tgldata = createdAt.getFullYear();
              if( tgldata >= tglmulai && tgldata <= tglselesai ) return a;
            });
                            myTable.clear();
                            $.each(resultProductData, function (index, value) {
                          myTable.row.add(value);
                        });
                        myTable.draw();
        })
        .catch(err => { throw err });

      }
    });
  });
```

Anyone could help? , so appreciate thanks 
and maybe if you not busy could you create/build in jsfiddle

Comment: share a fiddle with what you have tried

Comment: or could you just give me code for make number index, base my code in question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is from this [DataTables thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/52063/how-to-add-index-column-to-datatables) and should do what you want. It's using an additional column for the indexes:

```
dataTable.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
       dataTable.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
           cell.innerHTML = i+1;
       } );
} ).draw();
```